# Where do public policy questions related to biology go?

Tags: discussion

## Background

I asked [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/93642/why-are-masks-still-required-for-covid-19-even-after-a-vaccine-is-produced?noredirect=1) on biology stack exchange to get the scientific reason behind Massachusetts' reopening policy of requiring masks even with a vaccine.

I thought I made sense to ask here, because there is a higher likelihood that this is the place where people are knowledgeable about virology could readily provide a relatively credible epidemiological reason behind the policy.  I would not expect the same from Politics.SE.

That said....I can see how it might be off topic. But I am just not sure which stack exchange to ask the question at this point.

## Question

Where do biologically related public policy questions belong?

Comment: You're correct that this question is *off-topic* here, which is why it garnered so many downvotes. It does seem it'd be more appropriate for Politics.SE, but I agree that you likely won't find the bio-informed expertise you're looking for. I personally know of no better place to ask this in the SE network. **I suggest posting a similar meta question to Meta.SE to reach a broader SE audience for help** (You can link back to this post to demonstrate Bio.SE is not appropriate). Also, remember, that very little public policy is ever actually well-informed and is often just reactionary :p ...

Comment: **Alternatively, you could modify this post to focus more on the biology to make it on-topic**. For example, you could ask a series of question posts about the effectiveness of mask-wearing, effectiveness of vaccines, herd-immunity, etc etc. However, I would assume the majority of on-topic, biologically-focused questions that get to the root of what you're asking are either already asked here (did you search?) or are likely still unknown for this specific emerging disease and will not receive a complete or definitive answer.

Comment: I'd add that while individual SE sites set their own rules for what is on- and off-topic at each site, there is not a cross-site intention to have every question that can be asked fall on-topic somewhere; many questions are not on-topic on any SE site.